# Find a succes line after validation scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have to read a cvs file and extract the rows that are correct and erroneous, I have a code that retrieves rows that are wrong, but I can not code the one that finds the correct values ​​in the cvs file

```
def getLineErrors[T](lines: Seq[ValidationNel[LineError, T]]): Seq[FailureZ[NonEmptyList[LineError]]] =
  lines.collect { case f @ FailureZ(_) => f }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does you mean `getLineSuccess` method for `collect` the `success` `validation` value? like this:

```
  def getLineSuccess[T](lines: Seq[ValidationNel[String, T]]): Seq[Success[T]] =
    lines.collect { case f: Success[T] => f }
```

need to call out, for `Success` `validation`, there is no `NonEmptyList` for error. Since `validation success` will return **value** directly.